# How do I move mp4 files from fotos to files on an ipad

Tags: video, airdrop, vlc, files.app

I airdropped 3 movies from my laptop to the ipad.  Since they were mp4's they ended up in fotos, but I'd rather watch them with VLC.  How do I get these files "moved" from fotos to files so that VLC can deal with them.  I've been working with .avi files up until now so it hasn't been a problem, but evidently fotos is claiming the mp4s and not even giving me a way to control where they go.

Comment: Can‘t you just use the Share Sheet to copy them to Files (or even directly to VLC)?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to do the following:

1. On your iPad launch the VLC app
2. Tap on the Network option
3. Enable the Sharing via WiFi option
4. This should present you with at least two http URL addresses
5. On your laptop, open your preferred web browser (Safari, etc)
6. Enter one of the URL addresses (**NOTE:** I find the numbered address is much more reliable than the one using your device name)
7. You browser will now open a Sharing via WiFi page
8. Use this page to directly upload/download files to/from VLC on your iPad.

Comment: Wow, had no idea this was in VLC.  Learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer files to and from *VLC* (and other supported apps) using **Finder** or **iTunes**.

#### MacOS Finder (macOS Catalina and later)

1. Connect your iPad by cable or same Wi-fi* network.
2. Open Finder and select your device the sidebar.
3. Go to Files section in the window.
4. Look for VLC in the list: Drag and drop the file on VLC to transfer it.

#### iTunes (macOS Mojave and earlier as well as Windows)

1. Connect your iPad by cable or same Wi-fi* network.
2. Open iTunes and select your device from the menu.
3. Go to File Sharing int he left sidebar.
4. Select VLC and drag and drop the file.

#### Note on Wi-fi

*Wi-fi: only works if you have connect by cable at least once before and selected the "Show this iPad when connected to WiFi" option in Finder or iTunes.

#### Guides from Apple

- **Finder**: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210598 \
- **iTunes**: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201301